# Why cannot $1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\dots}}}$ be equal to $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$?

Tags: fractions, continued-fractions

Why cannot $1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\dots}}}$ be equal to $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$?

I know that some of you will answer "because it is positive". I know it, but I don't know how to prove it. Maybe the second part is positive — how do you know that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe because the LHS is a positive number?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio .My question is exactly this why every body think it is positive?

Comment: You need to really understand what a continued fraction is. When you do the trick $1+1/x=x$ you aren't fully using the essence of what a continued fraction is. Look up how it is actually defined.

Comment: Well... how do you define $1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1+\dots}}}$?  I would think any reasonable definition would be the limit of the sequence:  $1, 1+\frac{1}{1}, 1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1}}, 1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1}}}, \dots$.  All of which are positive and this will converge upon a specific limit.

Comment: The infinite continued fraction is the limit of the finite continued fractions, all of which are clearly at least $1$.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: any truncation of the continued fraction leads to $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\geq 1$, since the sequence of Fibonacci numbers is increasing.

Comment: It seems like you don't understand the definition of a continued fraction. Look that up, and then the answer to your question about positivity shoudl be clear.

Comment: @anomaly.Yes it get clear but an answer will be nice.

Comment: Taha, I recommend you learn how to calculate the continued fractions for $\sqrt n,$ when $n$ is not a square, and $\frac{1 + \sqrt {4k+1}}{2},$ when $4k+1$ is not a square. This can be done at high school level, no real computer is required, but it helps to have an ordinary calculator. It may not appear that way now, but this will help your future studies. Also, there are probably lists of these continued fractions online ( they will all be eventually periodic, so a finite list of numbers completely specifies the C.F.) But do the calculations yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following answer summarizes the comments.  By definition, the value of a *continued fraction* $a_0 + \frac1{a_1 + \frac1{a_2 + \dots}}$ is the limit of its truncations to fractions.  Assuming the $a_i$s are positive, the sequence $s_0 = a_0, s_1 = a_0 + \frac1{a_1},\dots$ of truncations is alternating in the sense that $s_n$ is always strictly between $s_{n-1}$ and $s_{n-2}$.  The sequence therefore converges to a positive number.

The value $x$ of the continued fraction $1 + \frac1{1+\frac1{1+\dots}}$ solves $x = 1 + \frac1x$ since the operations $x \mapsto \frac1x$ and $y \mapsto 1+y$ are both continuous.  Since $x = 1 + \frac1x$ has a unique positive solution, $1 + \frac1{1+\frac1{1+\dots}}$ must converge to that solution.

---

I remark that the question is not entirely trivial, the comments above notwithstanding.  In particular, the formula "$\frac{1 + \sqrt 5}2$" can be interpreted either purely algebraically or in terms of the real numbers.  The real numbers distinguish between $\sqrt 5$ and $-\sqrt 5$: the former has a square root in $\mathbb R$ whereas the latter does not.  The rational numbers, if you do not consider any topology on them, do not distinguish between these two elements.  The field $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 5]$ has an automorphism taking $\sqrt 5$ to $-\sqrt 5$.

Fractions are purely algebraic, but continued fractions, being infinitary, necessarily involve topology.  One can study topologies on $\mathbb Q$ other than the one coming from $\mathbb R$ --- indeed, such study is very important throughout modern mathematics.  One could imagine that in some other topology, the continued fraction at question would have a limit, and if in that topology you can distinguish $\pm \sqrt 5$, perhaps the limit might be $\frac{1-\sqrt 5}2$.

I know of no topology for which that works, however.  The topologies on $\mathbb Q$ usually studied are: (0) the "real" topology, whose completion is $\mathbb R$, which ultimately can be derived from the idea that as you continue to add $1$ to an integer, you get further and further away from $0$; (p) the "$p$-adic topology", whose completion is $\mathbb Q_p$, which ultimately can be derived from the declaration that multiplying by $p$ (some chosen prime) moves you *closer* to $0$, and multiplying by numbers relatively prime to $p$ doesn't change your distance from $0$.

In $p$-adic topologies, continued fractions tend not to converge at all.  For example, the truncations of $1 + \frac1{1+ \frac1{1+\dots}}$ are ratios $F_{n+1} / F_{n}$ of Fibonacci numbers.  For any given prime $p$, occasionally the $n$th Fibonacci number $F_n$ will be divisible by a large power of $p$ (in which case $F_{n+1}$ will not be divisible by $p$ at all), making $F_n$ very small for the $p$-adic topology, making $F_{n+1} / F_{n}$ very large, thereby preventing the sequence of truncations from converging.

Comment: I think it is better not to comment on the courtesy of others *as part of an answer.*

Comment: @quid I have removed the parenthetical remark, because I wasn't sure of whether to include it, and because I certainly think whether and how to call out courtesy of others is a complicated question. I've seen much worse behavior here and on MO, and I know I sometimes forget to be polite myself. (I should also mention that I spend much more time on MO than here, so I don't entirely know the culture.) In this case, I felt like there was something to complain about, but only barely. Likely tone-of-voice clues are all I was missing.

Comment: I have no issue with you remarking on it, it should just not be part of the answer IMO (note the emphasis). Thanks for removing it from the answer.